# How do I intervene in middle of GO automation testing during tests execution?

Tags: go, automated-tests

I am currently executing a series of tests on a Hardware device which gets input from the load in the form of Volts, Amperes.etc.
I input various different parameters of load on the device before testing.It runs successfully and gives out a series of test results.

[Output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNhCp.png)

These are the testing I employ

- ToleranceTest
- EqualsTest
- BooleanTest
- LookupIntTest
- LookupStrTest
- NotEqualsTest

**I just want to know *refer:output image* that before running the next test can we have an operator intervention. For example, plugging and removing sensors**

So the execute process needs to cater for this input

Had tried to make provision in the json file - it may need some thinking as to whether it will work. 
The json file is in this format

```
"EXEC_HANDLE": {
    "CLI": {
        "ADDITIONAL_PARAMS": ""
    },
    "MAXLATENCY": {
        "TITLE": "Ensure test performed is done within expected time frame (milliseconds)",
        "TYPE": "Range",
        "MAX": "220",
        "MIN": "50"
    },
    "RESULTSET": {
        "TITLE": "Result set from polling has expected quantity of records",
        "TYPE": "Range",
        "MAX": 100,
        "MIN": 5
    }
},
"TEST_REGIME": [
  {
      "TITLE": "L1 Amps Load",
      "NAME": "L1_A",
      "TYPE": "Tolerance",
      "HAMEG_VALUE": "AMPS",
      "TOLERANCE": 0.5
  }
...
...
```

Could be a transaction in the database we need to be recording the execution
Or possible a touched file?

**open to suggestions**

I'd rather not be dependent on a database as I may want to execute tests outside of our test environment

**Maybe the console is waiting for a key press from a user, but if a file is touched/removed, the process can continue non-interactively**

Comment: sorry your question isn't specific enough.  Voting to close as "Too Broad"

Comment: The Go testing framework was intended for _testing a corresponding Go program_. This doesn't seem to be what you're doing. You should probably be writing a normal Go program, not a Go test suite. This is a classic square peg into round hole situation.

Comment: Thank You . It is working fine if we just use it as a normal program.